# converting date value from html form with dashes in wrong order to slashes in correct order

Tags: php, html

I have an html form that I am posting a date value in the following format:

2019-12-13

What I need (due to the software it is being imported into) is to format it like:

12/13/2019

what I tried:

```
$dateUSD = date($_POST['dateUSA'])->format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

it did not work..

also trying to just change the - to /:

```
$dateUSD = $_POST['dateUSA'];
//2019-12-12

$dateUSD = str_replace('-', '/', $dateUSD);
```

But htat is not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just try this :**

```
$date="2019-12-13";
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date));
```

**Output :**
13/12/2019

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$date=date_create("2019-12-13");
echo date_format($date,"d/m/Y");
```

**Result :**

```
13/12/2019
```